# replace the first two character in JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to replace the first two string from JSON object

my JSON object is

```
{userName: "TT-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"}
```

I need to update my JSON object to

```
{userName: "LL-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"}
```

how can I do that? I tried with string `replace` method but it not working for me

**EDIT:**

The character[s] will not be `TT` it may be anything. I need to replace the first two characters of the string

Comment: Parse the string into a real object, change the value, stringify it again if you need it as a string.

Comment: do you have an object or a [JSON](http://json.org/) compliant string? which two strings do you mean? actually there is only one property/string which is different.

Comment: A JSON object isn't a thing.  What is it you have, a javascript object, or a string of JSON in a file somewhere?

Comment: `my_obj.userName = my_obj.userName.replace('TT', 'LL');` ?

Comment: You character or string ?

Comment: @CodeManiac sorry i need to update the character

Comment: You need to be more specific about your question, your current code, and your requirements, otherwise everyone is just guessing.

Comment: do you know the property or do you like to replace all strings in the object?

Comment: @techie18 if not fixed than mention in question properly

Comment: So what exactly they need to be replaced with ? What have you tried (code please) ? How did it fail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace "TT" or ANY character with "LL":

`/^.{2}/`

See working example below:

```js
let my_obj = {userName: "TT-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"};

my_obj.userName = my_obj.userName.replace(/^.{2}/, 'LL');
console.log(my_obj);
```

Or, as others have pointed out, you can use `substr`/`substring` to remove the first two characters in the string:

```
my_obj.userName = "LL" + my_obj.userName.substr(2);
```

Note:- g flag is not needed as we are matching only first two character

Comment: Need to use regex?  What about "LL" + string.substring(2); ?

Comment: @techie18 no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
objName.objectPropertyName = objName.objectPropertyName.replace(/^.{2}/, 'LL');
```

```js
let obj = {userName: "TT-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"};

obj.userName = obj.userName.replace(/^.{2}/, 'LL');

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use .userName = "LL-RRR-000"; and it will modify your object.

var x = {userName: "TT-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"};
x.userName = "LL-RRR-000";

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {userName: "TT-RRR-000", sName: "KLIU"}

obj.userName = obj.userName.replace(obj.userName.substr(0,2),"LL");

console.log(obj);
```

You have to assign it back to the object if you want to change the original object.